# Append table via jQuery

Tags: jquery, append, iccube

I am trying to automatically add a table to a report after the end of the loading process. I tried that using the jQuery .append() Method on the report (context.$report):

```
function consumeEvent( context, event ) {                                
    if (event.name == 'ic3-report-after-build') {
        context.$report.append( "<table>...</table>" );
    }                                                                       
}
```

Unfortunately nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `context.$report` is a jQuery object? If so what does `console.log(context.$report.length);` output in your console?

Comment: I hoped, that it is a jQuery object. context.$report.length shows 1. Here is a short description about this in icCube and I hoped, something like this could work... http://www.iccube.com/livedemo/?ic3reportName=Javascript%20Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correct code, but still it should be enhanced a bit.

Try this one:

**Report JavaScript**

```
function consumeEvent( context, event ) {                                
    if (event.name == 'ic3-report-after-build') {
        context.$report.find('table#custom').remove()
        context.$report.find('.ic3-report-content-container')
        .append('<table id="custom"><tr><td>Table</td></tr></table>')
    }                                                                       
}
```

**Report CSS**

```
table#custom {
    border: 1px solid #black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes the CSS was neccesary. So apparently I had the table there, just didn't see it ^^ Thank you very much!